# ogr2ogr params "PROMOTE_TO_MULTI" useage in java

Tags: java, gdal, ogr2ogr

I want copy shapefile into postgis, and I use the command " ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=db user=user password=pwd host=host port=port" -nln test -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI "D:\spaceData\shp(1)\city_clip.shp" ". it wrok well. but i don't know "PROMOTE_TO_MULTI " how to set in java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Load GDAL library
    gdal.AllRegister();

    // Input File shp and PostGIS connection parameters
    String filePath = "D:\\spaceData\\shp(1)\\city_clip.shp";
    String postgisConnectionString = "PG:dbname=your_db user=user password=pwd " +
            "host=host port=port";

    // Open the File Geodatabase
    DataSource fileDS = ogr.Open(filePath, 0);

    // Open the PostGIS database
    DataSource postgisDS = ogr.Open(postgisConnectionString, 1);
    for (int i =0;i<fileDS.GetLayerCount();i++){
        // Get the layer from the FileDS
        Layer layer = fileDS.GetLayer(i);

        Vector vec =  new Vector();
        // PROMOTE_TO_MULTI doesn't work
        vec.add("PROMOTE_TO_MULTI=YES");
        postgisDS.CopyLayer(layer,"test",vec);
    }

    // Close the data sourcesd
    fileDS.delete();
    postgisDS.delete();
}
```